# Abrir projeto/solução asp.net que estão vindo de outra máquina

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis

Eu tenho um projeto que foi criado em uma máquina e eu tenho que dar manutenção nele.

Copiei o projeto para minha máquina atual e quando tento abrir a solution/project obtenho a seguinte  mensagem do Visual Studio:

> http://localhost:52961 : error  : Error opening web http://localhost:52961. The Web Site 'http://localhost:52961' is configured to use IIS Express as the web server but the URL is currently configured on the local IIS web server. To open this Web Site, you must use IIS Manager to remove the bindings using this URL from the local IIS web server.

Com isso percebi que o projeto está rodando com iis express e não o local.

Tentei criar um novo site no IIS local com localhost:52961 e colocar os arquivos da minha solução lá dentro, mas obtenho erro do IIS no browser, a mensagem de erro é:

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
>
> The requested page can not be accessed because the configuration data related to the page is invalid.

Realmente nunca mexi com IIS e ASP.NET por isso posso estar cometendo coisas muito erradas.

Eu gostaria de abrir o projeto com o IIS express da mesma maneira que está configurado no projeto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja o que o erro diz:

> The Web Site 'http://localhost:52961' is configured to use IIS Express as the web server **but the URL is currently configured on the local IIS web server.**

Ou seja, o seu projeto está configurado para usar o IIS Express com a URL **localhost:52961**, porém, esta URL está configurada em algum site no IIS local.

Então, abra o IIS local, encontre o site que está usando esta URL nos *bindings* e troque o endereço ou remova o site.

Comment: Sim. Eu fiz isso.

Agora a seguinte mensagem de erro aparece no visual studio:

http://localhost:52961 : error  : Error opening web http://localhost:52961. Unable to open the Web site 'http://localhost:52961'.  The Web server 'http://localhost:52961' could not be found. 

Como eu trouxe esse projeto de outra máquina, eu provavelmente terei que configurar o iis express pra conseguir abrir nessa máquina nova? Se sim, como posso executar essa configuração?

Comment: Em que momento?

Comment: @DenisPolicarpo Não, o IIS Express é configurado pelo arquivo do Visual Studio.

Comment: Essa mensagem de erro aparece no momento quando eu tento abrir o projeto no visual studio, quando ele está tentando carregar o projeto.

Comment: Abra o arquivo SLN num editor de texto e procure pelo texto **UseIISExpress**

Comment: Tinha essa linha, mas não estava setada. Setei ela para: UseIISExpress = "true"

Agora a aplicação é carregada, mas quando tento abrí-la no browser um erro aparece. Vou editar meu post principal acima para postar a mensagem de erro.

Comment: @DenisPolicarpo Se tu resolveu o primeiro erro. Abre uma pergunta com o novo, ficar editando a pergunta não é boa ideia...

Comment: Beleza...vou abrir um novo tópico...muito obrigado!